# is not a subtype of type 'String' ..Retrieving 4 fields from firebase single collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get 4 fields from the firebase collection (all fields in the same collection, each document has these 4 fields) into a list which needs to be filtered in different ways after getting data locally

I am getting this error type 'speakerNamesModel' is not a subtype of type 'String'. what is my mistake? Please give a sample code.

```
    class speakerNamesModel {
    String speakerlanguage;
    String speakername_en;
    String speakername_lo;
    String speach_audiourl;
    speakerNamesModel(
    this.speakerlanguage, this.speakername_en,              this.speakername_lo, this.speach_audiourl);

    speakerNamesModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJSON)
    : speakerlanguage = parsedJSON['speakerlanguage'],
    speakername_en = parsedJSON['speakername_en'],
    speakername_lo = parsedJSON['speakername_lo'];
    speach_audiourl = parsedJSON['speach_audiourl'];
    }

    Future<List<speakerNamesModel>> getspeakerNamesList() async {
    QuerySnapshot qShot =
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection                 ('speakernames').get();
    return qShot.docs
    .map((doc) => speakerNamesModel(
    doc.data()["speachdate"],     //timestamp data
    doc.data()["speakerlanguage"],//string
    doc.data()["speakername_en"], //name in roman letters string
    doc.data()["speakername_lo"],//name in local language unicode 
    doc.data()["speach_audiourl"],  //string
    ))
    .toList();
    }

    @override
    void initState() {
    getspeakerNamesList().then((List data) {
    setState(() {
    speakernames = filteredspeakernames = data;
    });
    });
```

Comment: Where does this error occure? The code seems to work for me. What type are `speakernames` and 'filteredspeakernames' of?

Comment: I have declared it like this  
List speakernames = [];

List filteredspeakernames = [];

Comment: okay, can you say in which line the error occures? Where does it say `type 'speakerNamesModel' is not a subtype of type 'String'`?

Comment: Thanks Your clue gave me the solution. After declaring like this   List<SpeakerNamesModel> Speakernames;
  List<SpeakerNamesModel> filteredSpeakernames; issue is solved. Thanks once again.

Comment: Could you please post the answer so anyone else can view how you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Just for tracking and as @subramanian-v mentions, the issue was solved by declaring their variables as follows:

```dart
List<SpeakerNamesModel> Speakernames;
List<SpeakerNamesModel> filteredSpeakernames;
```